# How-to return a const std::vector<Object *const>?

Tags: c++, stl, constants, encapsulation

I have a class with a container (containing pointer) as a member:

```
MyClass{
private:
   std::vector<MyObject*> _VecMyObjs;
public:
   const std::vector<MyObject* const> GetVecMyObj();
}
```

Now I try to implement GetVecMyObj(). Here is what I came up with...

```
const vector<MyObject *const> ACI_CALL MyClass::GetVecMyObjs()
{
   const vector<MyObject *const> VecMyObjs;
   VecMyObjs.assign( _VecMyObjs.begin(), _VecMyObjs.end());
   return VecMyObjs;
}
```

But of course the compiler is warning me, that I use the assign-function on a const-Object. Is there a better way to do this? I mean, I don't want VecMyObjs to change VecMyObj outside of the class, of course. How can I achieve that without a compiler warning?

EDIT:
Okay. Thank you everybody. It's now like this:

```
const vector<MyObject *const> ACI_CALL MyClass::GetVecMyObjs()
{
   const vector<MyObject *const> VecMyObjs;
   VecMyObjs.assign( _VecMyObjs.begin(), _VecMyObjs.end());
   return VecMyObjs;
}
```

But, I can't get around the assign-function, right? E.g. casting the "original" doesn't work, if I want "everything" to be constant.

Comment: You don't need VicMyObjs to be const inside the GetVecMyObjs function... that qualification will be added implicitly when it is returned.

Comment: Are you sure you want vector<MyObject* const> and not vector<MyObject const*>? And why is returning by reference to const not feasible?

Comment: about your edit that you want everything to be constant: as others already pointed out, you are making the pointers const, not the pointed objects.  These can be changed, thus changing your internal objects.

Comment: @stefaanv: Good point! I think/hope my final solution is taking care of that. (see below)

Comment: Even if you wanted a `std::vector< MyObject* const >` you can't have one as the template argument to a `vector` must be an assignable type and `const` objects are not (generally) assignable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure `std::vector<MyObject * const>` (vector of constant pointers) is really what you want : I believe you mean `std::vector<MyObject const *>` (vector of pointer to constant objects).

1. The "first level" of constness (*pointer* constness) is naturally achieved by returning a constant reference on the vector. Only `const_iterator` can be obtained from a const vector, so you have a guarantee that the pointers won't be modified (but *pointees* can be).
2. The "second level" of constness (*pointee* constness) is harder to obtain. Either return a new instance of a vector as already pointed out by others :

   ```
   return std::vector<const MyObject *>(_VecMyObjs.begin(), _VecMyObjs.end());
   ```

   Or, if applicable, try to look into the [Boost Pointer Container](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_container.html) library (and most notably [ptr_vector](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_vector.html)) which offers, among other things, correct constness propagation :

   > Propagates constness such that one
   >   cannot modify the objects via a
   >   const_iterator.

You have to understand that returning a const reference on a vector guarantees that it cannot be modified (no insertion, deletion, or modification of its value). So, in most cases, returning a `const std::vector<T> &` is the way to go because if does not involve any copying. The issue here is really specific to container of pointers, where constness of the values does not provide constness of the pointees.

Comment: Thanks, I knew there was something like that...Maybe I should start another question-thread, but what is the difference between "std::vector<const MyObject * const> and "const vector<const MyObject *> then? Or is it the same?

Comment: @AudioDroid: no : you can modify a non-const vector (`push_back`, `erase`, ...), while you can't modify a const vector (which, in a sense, only provides read-only access to the already stored elements). However, regarding const-ness *of the elements*, they offer the same guarantee.

Comment: Great. Thanks! If you can double-check my own answer....I hope I understood you completely.

Comment: if you have vector<T*> then a const vector<T*> & means you cannot change the elements in the vector and you cannot add new ones but it does not change the pointers into pointers-to-const.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to return a fresh `vector`, don't make it `const`. Put the `const` keyword before the `*`.

```
std::vector<MyObject const*> MyClass::GetVecMyObj()
{
    return std::vector<MyObject const*>(_VecMyObjs.begin(), _VecMyObjs.end());
}
```

I omitted the conversion to `TRoadSgmt` as you didn't specify the inheritance of this class.

Comment: Oops, [TRoadSgmt] wasn't meant to be in this general example. I just corrected it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the vector of the non-const pointers resides somewhere during the entire lifetime that you are going to use the const-version so you don't need a copy, and if there a lot of them so you don't want to copy the vector, you are better off returning some kind of wrapper object that is custom made to only give the user const-access.

The address of the first element of the vector will be T** and you can't cast that to const T** (correctly) nor can you cast it to const T*const * (which would be safe but the language does not allow it).

If you were allowed to convert the latter it would be perfect for creating a read-only view.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from changing the signature to remove the `const` from the `vector` (as it's a copy of the vector), I'm assuming that you don't want people outside to modify the contents, as a result, make a `const` pointer , i.e.

```
vector<const MyObject *> ACI_CALL MyClass::GetVecMyObjs()
{
   return vector<const MyObject *>(_VecMyObjs.begin(), _VecMyObjs.end());
}
```

Now the returned vector is a copy, which contain const pointer (which means you can't modify the pointed object via this pointer) - well that's the agreement, there's nothing preventing someone from `const_cast`ing that away (using that is UB anyways!)

If you really want to prevent modifications, return a copy (or clone of each object) in the vector.

Comment: The `const` keyword in the declaration of `VecMyObjs` gives an error.

Comment: I though the syntax "const vector<MyObject*>, makes sure that the "content" of the vector (in this case: all the pointers to MyObjects) constant.

Comment: @larsmans - teach me for blindly copying! Thx, fixed. @AudioDroid, I don't think so, it only makes the `vector` object constant, I don't believe there are any guarantees about what it holds..

Comment: Should add, I would also use the constructor of `vector` directly rather than assign as indicated by @Frerich in that answer, though the `const` syntax is slightly different.

Answer (score 0):

```
const vector<const MyObject *> MyClass::GetVecMyObjs() const
{
   return vector<const MyObject *>(_VecMyObjs.begin(), _VecMyObjs.end());
}
```

This seems to be the solution to me. I can tell now, thanks to all the different posts I got.
Thanks all of you! Have a nice one...
(Or let me know, if I am still wrong somewhere.)

Comment: you are returning a new vector instance, so there is no point in making the returned vector const (it's a copy anyway, why would you care if the caller `push_back` something into it ?).

Comment: @icecrime: Calling a mutating operation on a temporary is very likely to be an error. Returning a `const` object catches client code that makes an incorrect assumption, perhaps that they are operating on a reference. Preventing `clz.GetVecMyObjs().push_back(x)` is probably a good thing. Returning a `const` object doesn't inhibit normal copying of the return value, e.g. `vector<const MyObject*> cpy = clz.GetVecMyObjs(); cpy.push_back(x);`.

Comment: @Charles Bailey: you're right, that's something I hadn't considered